# Using BeautifulSoup to fetch data and send to another browser tab

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm just recently starting python and I'm looking for a way to automate a task I'm doing waaay too much by hand on a daily basis. What i'm currently doing is copying these two fields manually, copying to clipboard before I use these values in my next browser tab which is an SMS-sender. It has two textfields where I want to input them both to each their field. Is this doable?

I have a website that I want to extract data from. The HTML on the website looks like this:

```
<dl>        
<dt>Date of birth</dt>   
<dd>01.01.1900</dd>

<dt>Name</dt>
<dd>Name of person</dd>

<dt>Id</dt>
<dd>212780</dd> <- I want this

<dt>Email</dt>
<dd>email@email.com</dd>

<dt>Day phone</dt>
<dd>01234567</dd>

<dt>Mobile phone</dt>
<dd>12345678</dd>  <-- I want this       
</dl>
```

**I have marked the information I want copied**

So what I want copied to my clipboard is:

> 212780 12345678

Now I need to paste these into the textfields on my next browser tab. The first value goes in textbox2 and the second value in textbox1.

I've tried different approaches using beautifulsoup, but I can't get it right. This is what I have had most luck with, but this is printing the values. Can anyone help me in the right direction?

```
import re

def find_by_label(soup, label):
    return soup.find("d1", text=re.compile(label)).next_sibling
```

And using ut like this:

```
find_by_label(soup, "Mobile phone").strip()
```

I appreciate any help! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

i guess you are looking for Id and Mobile Phone values, so try something

```
data = BeautifulSoup("""<dl>        
<dt>Date of birth</dt>   
<dd>01.01.1900</dd>

<dt>Name</dt>
<dd>Name of person</dd>

<dt>Id</dt>
<dd>212780</dd>

<dt>Email</dt>
<dd>email@email.com</dd>

<dt>Day phone</dt>
<dd>01234567</dd>

<dt>Mobile phone</dt>
<dd>12345678</dd> 
</dl>""")

dts = data.find_all('dt')
dds = data.find_all('dd')

for i in range(len(dts)):
    if 'Id' in dts[i].text:
        print(dds[i].text)
    if 'Mobile phone' in dts[i].text:
        print(dds[i].text)
```

Ouput

```
212780
12345678
```

Comment: Thank you for this. How would this work if I wanted to use it on several webpages? The HTML would be the same on each webpage, but the values would be different.

Also, how could I turn this into a script where I paste the webpage I want to extract this from with each run of the script? So that when i run the .py file it asks me what URL it should fetch from, then fetching the values and storing it in clipboard?

Comment: if the html is same then just create a list of the urls and then keep looping through the list with the requests.get(url) code inside it..

Comment: Yes, this is a customer portal. So every single page will have the same HTML, but the values in "Id" and "Mobile phone" will be different each time. So manually adding the HTML like above will not work.

The first script does what it's supposed to by printing the value. However the whole point of this is that I don't have to manually go get the values from the webpage and paste into the script.

How would this code look like if I just want the script to ask me which URL it should fetch from, and then posting the result?